# Securing NFS in a multihomed environment

Tags: virtualbox, firewall, nfs, file-sharing

In a virtualised environment (VirtualBox with host-only networking) I want to share a *folder on the host* with the guest via NFS. I think that to achieve this, I should bind the NFS listening port to the virtual host interface of the host-only network (so not to the host physical device).

How can I bind the NFS sever daemon only to a specific interface?
To avoid IP spoofing from other boxes sitting in the same network as the host, can I bind NFS to the interface as a device (`vboxnet0`), instead that to its  IP?

With regard to the latter, it seems to me that `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` only speak in terms of `service:IPs`

Answer (score 0):

You specify to which host you export to in `/etc/exports`.

So you will write entry like this:

```
/data 192.168.1.1(rw)
```

Assuming you use some kind of Redhat. On client, mount using:

```
mount 192.168.1.5:/data /data
```

Comment: Thanks. Since you use IPs and not interface names, what if another box pretends to be 192.168.1.1 spoofing the packet sources?

Comment: You're missing the point of his Q. He's asking how to restrict access to the autofs daemon, so that it's not bound to all interfaces on the server, but to one.